# (Adaptive) thresholding in opencv error (Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat) 

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, threshold

I'm trying to use thresholding on my video stream but it is not working.

My video stream:

```
Mat *depthImage = new Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC1, Scalar::all(0));
```

Then i try to do the adaptive thresholding, (also doesn't work with regular thresholding)

```
for(;;){

    if( wrapper->update()){


        wrapper->getDisplayDepth(depthImage);

        cvAdaptiveThreshold(depthImage, depthImage,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY,75,10);


        imshow("Depth", *depthImage);

    }

    int k = waitKey(25);
    if(k == 27 ) exit(0);
}
```

I get this error :

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /Users/olivierjanssens/source/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 646
>   terminate called throwing an exception

What am i doing wrong, i can get display and see the stream perfectly.But when i add this thresholding i get the error previously mentioned. (i'm rather new to opencv btw).

Thx in advance !

Comment: Are you sure that this line is correct? `imshow("Depth", *depthImage);`

Comment: yes, because that line works without the thresholding line. And if i remove it nothing changes in this setup.

Comment: And if i put the threshold line in comment and add for example this : 'cvCircle(depthImage, cvPoint(point.X, point.Y), 20, cvScalar(0,255,0), 1);' To draw a circle it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your depthImage is a pointer to a cv::Mat, which to me seems strange...

...but, if you're using the C++ syntax then you'll want to use the [C++ version of adaptiveThreshold](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold), which deals with `cv::Mat`, with the following definition:

```
void adaptiveThreshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, double maxValue,
    int adaptiveMethod, int thresholdType, int blockSize, double C);
```

which will need prefixed by `cv::` if you're not using that namespace already.

For example:

```
Mat *depthImage; // Obtain this using your method
Mat image = *depthImage;  // Obtain a regular Mat to use (doesn't copy data, just headers)

adaptiveThreshold(image, image,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY,75,10);

imshow("Depth Image", *depthImage);
// OR
imshow("Depth Image", image);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. I'm still a bit new to c++, so sorry for the strange question.

Comment: When using edge detection, should i use  cvCanny( depthImage, depthImage, 1.0, 1.0, 3); ? or use that image variable ?

Comment: I defined that `Mat image` because I don't like working with pointers, and because that's generally the way most of the C++ OpenCV functions are geared up. If you could change how you get the image from your video stream (you don't post any of those details so I don't know if you can) to provide a `Mat` to your code rather than a `Mat*` then it would be easier.

Comment: Also, remember you're wanting the C++ functions from OpenCV, see [cv::Canny documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#canny) and that reference site in general.

Comment: Yes i had a look, the way you defined works. I'm working with a wrapper and i currently don't want to change anything in the wrapper, so your way is perfect :).

Comment: Also, remember that the way the OpenCV `Mat` structure is set up, the assignment `Mat image = *depthImage` doesn't copy any data, it just sets up new headers for image pointing to the same data stored at depthImage. So using either one in further functions will modify both.